# Creating image caption from alt script

Tags: jquery, image, tags, caption

I am trying to use this jQuery script to make an image caption from the alt tag:

```
$("#content img").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var title = $this.attr("alt");
$this.after('<div class="caption">'+ title +'</div>');
});
```

I am using another jQuery script before it and it is working fine. I can't seem to get the caption to alt script to work.

Example: www.cslack.com/test.html

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: From looking at your example page, you should add the position absolute styling to the `<a>` tag or better yet a wrapper around each link that wraps an image. That way when you do add the caption, it will also be positioned in the same place as the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $(function(){

   $('a > img[style]').each(function(){
       $el = $(this);
       var style = $el.attr('style');
       $el.attr('style','');
       $el.parent().attr('style',style);
    }); //Moves the inline styles

      $("img").each(function(){
          var title = this.alt;
          $(this).after('<div class="caption">'+ title +'</div>');
      }); //Adds the dynamic captions.
 });
```

Comment: No, don't use `append` instead of `after`.  Calling `append` will put the `div` _inside_ the `<img>` tag, which is not what he wants.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I still am not quite able to get it working. I am pretty new to this. Would you mind taking another look?

Comment: It looks find. Doing what is advertised!
OK-- your javascript is fine (although it's a good idea to only include jQuery once in the page).
However, your problem lies within the css styling of each image.
I'd move the style="position..." to the <a name=""> element instead of the <img src=... element it's on now, then the captions will be moved along with the images.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you're executing your code before the images exist.

You need to wrap the code in `$(function() { code })` to make it run after the document loads.

Alternatively, you can move the `<script>` block to the end of the `<body>` tag after the `img` tags.

Also, your HTML doesn't have a `#content` element; you need to either change the selector to `img` or put all of the `<img>` tags inside a `<div id='content'>`.

Answer (score 1):

On your example page, there is no such thing as `#content` which is why it doesn't work.

If you place a `<div id="content">` around your content, then it should work.

Comment: +1 for the quick find, alternatively (and probably a slightly better solution in this case) you could just remove the #content and just leave $("img") which will select each img on the page.